# Unable to open Software Center

Tags: package-management, software-center

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04LTS and can't open the Software Center. The application opens and tries to load but just closes.

```
Running from the command line presents this output:
 software-center
2015-10-10 18:21:31,807 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-10-10 18:21:32,327 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2015-10-10 18:21:32,329 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2015-10-10 18:21:32,385 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2015-10-10 18:21:33,036 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2015-10-10 18:21:33,037 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
    self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
    0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 68 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Please assist!

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions.

1) Simple reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center

sudo apt-get install software-center
```

2) Remove `/var/lib/apt/lists`:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Does this work?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, this did not work.